# Error Converting In OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I keep getting an error of

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

when I run my query.  How should this be altered in order for the query to execute succesfully?

```
Declare @Table1 Table (name varchar(100), d1 date, amt float)
Insert Into @Table1 (name, d1, amt) Values
('Red', '01/01/2015', '14.00'), ('Red', '01/01/2016', '23.00'),
('Red', '01/03/2015', '22.00'), ('Red', '02/01/2015', '33.00'),
('Red', '03/04/2015', '10,00'), ('Red', '04/04/2016', '10.00'),
('Pink', '01/01/2015', '4.00'), ('Pink', '04/05/2016', '5.00')

DECLARE @ItemList nvarchar(500) = N'''Red''';
DECLARE @startdate date = N'''01/01/2015''';
DECLARE @enddate date = N'''12/31/2015''';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = N'Select *
FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 
''Select
name
,SUM(CAST(amt As DECIMAL(10,2)) [Total]
FROM @Table1
WHERE name IN ('+ REPLACE(@ItemList, '''', '''''') + N')
    AND d1 BETWEEN ('+ REPLACE(@startdate,'''', '''''') + N')
AND ('+ REPLACE(@enddate,'''', '''''') + N')
''
);
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**EDIT**
It is a postgresql database that I am querying, but created a table variable for simplicity and to show DDL

Comment: Why are you doing this as dynamic sql?

Comment: Due to the need of using openquery to accomplish it.  It is a postgresql database that I am querying, but created a table variable for simplicity and to show DDL

Comment: You should definitely stop using ambiguous American date format and format your dates yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @MarkSinkinson - even altering the dates to a yyyy/mm/dd format still produces the same error

Comment: Can't you build the SQL statement separately?  If it's possible, it would remove some complexity and make debugging easier.

Comment: The additional quotes around the date parameters are the problem there. Given that you are just passing them as strings it would be best to just set them as nvarchar parameters (otherwise you would want to cast the date parameters as nvarchar in the where clause)

Comment: @Nic - can you provide example so I can see syntax?

Comment: @dezso - I am doing it this way so I can pass parameters to the OPENQUERY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra quotes around dates are a problem (as an aside you cannot pass character strings into float columns, which is why your table variable insert also fails).

Using extra quotes can be done at the dynamic layer, and using CHAR(39) rather than embedding a whole load of quotes can make the code a lot more readable don the line.

As an addition, initially selecting out the dynamic SQL so that you can run the generated statement in another window to test your results is also a good thing when starting out.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
    (
      name VARCHAR(100) ,
      d1 DATE ,
      amt FLOAT
    );
INSERT  INTO @Table1
        ( name, d1, amt )
VALUES  ( 'Red', '01/01/2015', 14.00 ),
        ( 'Red', '01/01/2016', 23.00 ),
        ( 'Red', '01/03/2015', 22.00 ),
        ( 'Red', '02/01/2015', 33.00 ),
        ( 'Red', '03/04/2015', 10.00 ),
        ( 'Red', '04/04/2016', 10.00 ),
        ( 'Pink', '01/01/2015', 4.00 ),
        ( 'Pink', '04/05/2016', 5.00 );

DECLARE @ItemList NVARCHAR(500) = N'''Red''';
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '01/01/2015';
DECLARE @enddate DATE = '12/31/2015';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'Select *
FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 
''Select
name
,SUM(CAST(amt As DECIMAL(10,2)) [Total]
FROM @Table1
WHERE name IN (' + REPLACE(@ItemList, '''', '''''') + N')
    AND d1 BETWEEN (' + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)
    + CAST(@startdate AS NVARCHAR(500)) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + N')
AND (' + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CAST(@enddate AS NVARCHAR(500)) + CHAR(39)
    + CHAR(39) + N')
''
);
';
SELECT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```